# How to add lanes to tikz bar plot

Tags: tikz-pgf, bar-chart

```
\documentclass[border=5mm] {standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots, pgfplotstable}


\begin{document}

\pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma]{
activity,start,end
$a1$,12,19
$b1$,25,32
$d1$,26,33
$e1$,35,40
$h1$,50,54
$a2$,17,23
$d2$,28,32
$c2$,30,38
$e2$,50,59
$g2$,70,73
$a3$,25,30
$c3$,32,35
$d3$,35,40
$e3$,45,50
$f3$,50,55
$b3$,60,65
$d3$,62,67
$e3$,80,87
$g3$,90,98
}\loadedtable

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
  nodes near coords xbar stacked configuration/.style={},
  nodes near coords style={font=\footnotesize},
  xbar stacked,
  xmin=5,
  xmax=105,
  bar width=0.2cm,
  axis lines=left,
  grid=both,
  major grid style={line width=.2pt,draw=gray!50},
  xlabel={time},
  width=\textwidth, height=7cm,
  enlarge y limits={abs=0.5},
  ytick=\empty,
]

\addplot [draw=none, forget plot] table [col sep=comma,x=start, y expr=-\coordindex]{\loadedtable};
\addplot [fill=black,
   nodes near coords,
   nodes near coords align={anchor=west},
   point meta=explicit symbolic] table[col sep=comma,x expr=\thisrow{end}-\thisrow{start}, y expr=-\coordindex,meta=activity]{\loadedtable};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

The above code generates the following tikz barchart:

[image: barchart in tikz]

I need to add lanes to the chart with labels in a way that the result is:
[image: barchart in tikz with lanes]

Answer (score 2):

By adding some "empty" bar charts and using extra ticks, I created the lanes, but i dont know how to centralize the lanes names

the empty bar charts are added by

```
,0,0
```

the extra ticks are added by

```
  extra y ticks = {-5,-11,-21},
    extra y tick labels={Case 1, Case 2, Case 3},
    extra y tick style={grid=major,major grid style={thick,draw=black}, dashed, draw=black, tick label style={yshift=.5cm}}
```

The full code is:

```
\documentclass[border=5mm] {standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots, pgfplotstable}


\begin{document}

\pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma]{
activity,start,end
$a1$,12,19
$b1$,25,32
$d1$,26,33
$e1$,35,40
$h1$,50,54
,0,0
$a2$,17,23
$d2$,28,32
$c2$,30,38
$e2$,50,59
$g2$,70,73
,0,0
$a3$,25,30
$c3$,32,35
$d3$,35,40
$e3$,45,50
$f3$,50,55
$b3$,60,65
$d3$,62,67
$e3$,80,87
$g3$,90,98
,0,0
}\loadedtable

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
  nodes near coords xbar stacked configuration/.style={},
  nodes near coords style={font=\footnotesize},
  xbar stacked,
  xmin=5,
  xmax=105,
  ymin=-21,
  bar width=0.2cm,
  axis lines=left,
  grid=both,
  major grid style={line width=.2pt,draw=gray!70},
  xlabel={time},
  width=\textwidth, height=7cm,
  enlarge y limits={abs=0.5},
  ytick=\empty,
  extra y ticks = {-5,-11,-21},
    extra y tick labels={Case 1, Case 2, Case 3},
    extra y tick style={grid=major,major grid style={thick,draw=black}, dashed, draw=black, tick label style={yshift=.5cm}}
]

\addplot [draw=none, forget plot] table [col sep=comma,x=start, y expr=-\coordindex]{\loadedtable};
\addplot [fill=black,
   nodes near coords,
   nodes near coords align={anchor=west},
   point meta=explicit symbolic] table[col sep=comma,x expr=\thisrow{end}-\thisrow{start}, y expr=-\coordindex,meta=activity]{\loadedtable};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You could add the lane names as normal yticks, then you can choose approprate y-values, and not have to do shifting.

Comment: I tried that, but then these extra yticks line are showing. What can I change to hide them keeping only the label?

Comment: Change `grid=both` to `xmajorgrids`. You may also want to add `tickwidth=0` to hide the ticks.